# SQL - How to grab a column's value and place it on the end of a string as a new column's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-update, flyway

So I want to grab the primary key on a table with many rows and create a new column with those values placed at the end of a string. For example:

If the PK values are 1,2,3... 999, the new values in the new column should be DEV00001, DEV00002, DEV00003... DEV00999.

What I have so far
(The PK on this table is ID):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN EXTRA_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL

UPDATE table_name SET
EXTRA_ID='DEV0000'+ID
WHERE ID < 10

UPDATE UPDATE table_name SET
EXTRA_ID='DEV000'+ID
WHERE ID < 100

UPDATE table_name SET
EXTRA_ID='DEV00'+ID
WHERE ID < 1000
```

Would this work?
Any other workarounds are also welcome

Comment: What DBMS are you using? [Edit] the question and add the tag.

Answer (score 2):

No need for multiple queries. In SQL Server 2012 and higher, you can use `format()` to dynamically left-pad `id` with the relevant number of `0`s:

```
update table_name
set extra_id = 'DEV' + format(id, '00000')
```

Comment: Would that be possible if I'm adding it as a flyway script?

Comment: @Squidlie: I don't know about flyway. But this is regular SQL that you should be able to incorporate directly in a SQL script.

Comment: If it's regular SQL, Flyway will be fine with it.